# Extracting ONLY the Parameters from GA UTM URLs

Tags: excel, google-analytics

I would like to extract the parameters from tracking URLs but I only want the parameters. I found this very helpful formula to extract them from URLs. This formula solves the problem best for me except that I only want the parameters without "utm_xxx." I like the way I can drag it to a few columns

=IF((LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"utm_","")))/4

[Extract GA UTM parameters from URL in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005438/extract-ga-utm-parameters-from-url-in-excel?newreg=5143fef1e1b64b9aacf49834cbd528e8)

The sample urls given were:
http://www.site.com.br/porta-montada-sanfonada?utm_source=google&utm_medium=display&utm_term=468x60&utm_content=34545&utm_campaign=nome_campanha

http://www.site.com.br/torneira-para-banheiro-mesa-bica-baixa-cromada?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=carrossel&utm_term=120x600&utm_content=87648715&utm_campaign=nome_campanha

In case I am not being clear, I am hoping to just extract what is after "&" and, when it applies, before "=".

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to do what you want:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF((LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2;"utm_";"")))/4<COLUMN(A2);"";"utm_"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2;"utm_";REPT(" ";LEN($A2)));COLUMN(A2)*LEN($A2);LEN($A2)));"&";""));"utm_source=";"");"utm_medium=";"");"utm_campaign=";"");"utm_content=";"");"utm_term=";"")
```

Put the URL with UTMs in A2 and the formula in cell B2 and copy over and down (if there are other URLs):

Example based on this URL: http://www.site.com.br/porta-montada-sanfonada?utm_source=google&utm_medium=display&utm_term=468x60&utm_content=34545&utm_campaign=nome_campanha

[image]

**EDIT**

To add other parameters and get the value:

In formula in A2 add this at the start:

```
SUBSTITUTE(
```

and this at the end:

```
;"utm_expid=";"")
```

then copy over and down

Comment: Thanks for your help - this works great. My only question is how do I add a couple more parameters/columns to the formula? I have a couple more I would like to add. utm_expid & utm_referrer. I am trying to adjust it but I am not sure what I keep doing wrong.

Comment: In formula in A2 add this at the start: SUBSTITUTE( and this at the end: ;"utm_expid=";"") then copy over and down.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, I have a different method that is simpler and more intuitive.

See Google Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lUQlMS_mIwr2AyG_ey2W1ofBaSmUiwMxx99smPSpmqY/edit?usp=sharing

I would explain here, but it's easier to understand just by looking at the sheet.

Comment: This works really well - thanks! A little messy but so is my desk. ;)

Comment: Yup np! If you have additional parameters, add more columns and copy the formula in the preceding column. 1 more thing, I like this method as it doesn't search for the names of the parameters like "utm=*" or "cid=". This will save you some time bc you'll never have to manually insert parameters names. To clean up the mess, I grouped the search columns together. Click the "-" icon to group and display only the parameter values.

Comment: I agree because there are a few parameters that keep popping up - the problem is having them in the same column.

Comment: @Ted Do you want all parameters in the same column? Can you provide a spreadsheet with your desired input and desired output?

Comment: yes, that would be perfect - you are awesome - here is a sample I whipped up - I tried to think of all the UTMs I might be needing so hopefully I didn't leave any out: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1af9Jpn_UEbkLR472g34tuoisKyoq-TrP83TM-5Nrttg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Both answers in this post seem to do exactly what you asked. What efforts have you made to try to utilize either solution?

Comment: I have used them - they do work. Having the parameters in their own column was a request that I was hoping to work out & I thought you offered to find a solution.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. To combine all the UTMs with a line break, try using char(10) and concatenate. For ex =concatenate(UTMcell1&char(10)&UTMcell2&char(10))